# How to track Facebook Button Click?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a mobile app. In this, I have a button to share something on user's facebook wall. Example : a pop up msg comes with in app > user clicks share button > Facebook pops up with new window and msg > facebook has post button > user click post button > msg is written to the user's timeline.

Now, when user click that share button of my app - I can track that. But after this control goes to Facebook api and  user goes to facebook pop up where there is a Facebook button of "POST".

My question is - what are the ways available to make sure that user has clicked on that POST button and shared that msg on his timeline/wall?

can this be tracked via facebook app id in real time?

Comment: why does the user have to post something? what for? and do you prefill the message or does the user enter the message by himself?

Comment: I have a prefilled msg. User just need to click Post. Its same as sharing any other post.

Comment: well. time to read the platform policy then. prefilling is not allowed, and you will definitely not get through the review process with publish_actions.